# Load Javascript on runtime created Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have this view where I call a Modal that loads from a external html file.
Since the content of this Modal is generated in runtime, I have to load/reload my javascript files, right?

I've created a function that reloads my javascript files after this Modal is loaded and it works fine.

My Question: Is there any better way to accomplish this?

Comment: have you tried callback ?

Comment: A callback from when the Modal os loaded?
If that is what you meant, I'd still be reloading my Javascript Files, right?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to load a JS file when the external html file is included?

In the view:

```
<script>LoadJsAsync('/Scripts/modal-scriptName.js');</script>
```

In a JS file that is referenced:

```
function LoadJsAsync(jsPath) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.onreadystatechange = function () {
        // if (this.readyState == 'complete') { callFunctionFromScript(); }
    }
    script.src = jsPath;
    head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: This way, I understand that I'd be loading a new Javascript file. In my problem, I already have a Javascript loaded in my first HTML (the one that calls the Modal) and need the same Javascript to be loaded on the Modal.

jQuery is one of those Javascript files, for better Understanding.

Comment: If I were you I would have an independent JS file for the modal and load it the way I described. Reloading an existing JS is not a good practice and could have other issues. Loading a JS that is specific to the modal dynamically will only affect that modal.

Comment: But I have some functions that are used Inside AND Outside of this Modal. If I create another Javascript for the Modal, I'd be duplicating my code.

Comment: Move those functions to a common JS and just call them from the new JS file. I'm not saying duplicate your code, I'm saying reuse it in a different way.